# Mounting shared folder on Ubuntu on Virtual Box

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ubuntu-15.10

I have an Ubuntu 15.10 server running on virtual box 5.0. I followed the instructions and added a folder under network share and selected auto mount option. However, when I try to mount the share using

`$sudo mount -t vboxsf universal universal`

I get the following error:

`unknown fiilesystem type 'vboxsf'`

I have already installed the following package:

`$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso`

Not sure what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Bah. I figured it out. This fixed it:

`$sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem before, just click Devices-> Insert Guest Addition CD ... , then installation will begin.

Enjoy it, thanks.